# Prolog - generate and test, how to write a rule square(S)

Tags: prolog, integer, generator, perfect-square

I have to write a rule square(S) in Prolog that tests if a number S is the square of an integer returning false (ex. square(3)) or true (ex. square(4)).
I used already a rule that generates all integers between 0 and M:

```
isInteger(X,M) :- between(0,M,X).
```

Using this generator I have to write the rule square(S). How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: to use sqrt but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how to use it

Comment: @user1336326 '?- sqrt(4, X). X = 2.0.'

Comment: @user1336326 sorry, my previous comment probably isn't the best answer. `sqrt/2` is in SWI-Prolog's Quintus library, but the mathematical expression functor is probably better, so like this: `X is sqrt(4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it your way, you just need to check if S is the product of your generated integer multiplied by itself.  So you could do it like this:

```
isInteger(X,M) :- between(0,M,X).

square(N) :-
    isInteger(X, N),
    N is X * X.
```

I came up with another possible solution, using the `sqrt` arithmetical function from SWI-Prolog but I think there must be a more elegant one.

I initially expected it would be as simple as `X is sqrt(4), integer(X).` However, this doesn't work (at least not in SWI-Prolog 7.1.4), because `X` is unified with the float `2.0` and `integer(2.0)` is false (since integer is checking the data type, not the value of the number). But this works:

```
square_of_integer(N) :-
    Int is rationalize(sqrt(N)),
    integer(Int).
```

It depends on first giving a representation of N as a rational (which, in SWI-Prolog, 'are represented by the compound term rdiv(N,M)'). `2 is rationalize(2.0)`, i.e., rationalize evaluates to an integer for round numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not work as a solution for your homework, but here is one of many ways to do it using constraint logic programming in [ECLiPSe CLP Prolog](http://eclipseclp.org/):

```
:- lib(gfd).
square(S) :-
    sqr(_) #= S.
```

It means: S is a square if it's an integer and some other value (we don't care what value, so we use "throw-out" variable `_`) squared equals S.

All modern Prolog systems supports constraint logic programming, and the code will be similar to above.